# Parsing Json feed from Solr

Tags: jquery, json, rest, solr, getjson

I'm experiencing a strange behavior parsing feed from Solr. I dont get any response using the url1. But I get if I use url2 instead, In both cases I got responses putting the url directly into the browser. Please, what am I doing wrong?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var searchterms = $('#input_box').val();
  var searchfield = $('#dropdown').val();

  var url1 ="http://localhost:8983/solr/moogle/select?q="+searchfield+"%3A%28"+searchterms+"%29&wt=json&indent=true";
  var url2 = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/moogle/select/?wt=json&json.wrf=?&q='+searchfield+':('+searchterms+')'

  $.getJSON(url1, function(result){
     alert("hello"+result.response.docs[0].title);
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It's a browser cross-domain scripting issue associated with running Solr on a different port from the webpage. 
I fixed this issue by including `json.wrf=?` parameter in the URL:

```
"http://localhost:8983/solr/moogle/select?q="+searchfield+"%3A%28"+searchterms
+"%29&wt=json&indent=true&json.wrf=?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Damian,

There is no "no response" in Solr.
It's respond, either with data, error code, or full exception description.

Instead of checking "result.response.docs[0].title" try "result.responseHeader.status" or other value in response header that will point you to the error.

Running the query from browser is of course a bit different than running it from code.

Also check Solr logs which are very useful. If using Apache you may find it in the Apache server log directory, with a record per each query and the response.